# ember-auth authentication while testing ember.js app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, ember.js, ember-data, konacha

How does one go about authenticating a user while testing an ember application with ember-auth? I am using Konacha with mocha and chai and following the exact same testing structure as this app.. https://github.com/dgeb/ember_data_example. confused on how to keep the authentication persistent across the entire testing suite.